# Why is blended cost of unused elastic ips greater than its unblended cost in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I understand that blended cost is the least cost that is payable by a root account in aws. But I have found that blended cost of unused elastic ips and that of metric monitoring is greater than unblended cost. Can anyone explain why is it so.

Thank you.

Comment: That does seem counter-intuitive.  Can you provide some examples of the actual numbers you see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no cost for Elastic IP addresses while in use.You only pay for the Elastic IP when it's not attached to an instance. Thats why the cost is more.